# Find and replace Pipe using awk command

Tags: shell, awk, sed, scripting

I am trying to grep column 7th with pipe delimiter (`|`) data in that I have to removed pipe (`|`) from middle of text.

Sample file:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10
value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|"value7|text"|value8|value9|value10
```

Problem in column no.7 : In that I have to removed `|` from middle of text. `value7|text`

Required output for column 7 is: `value7 text`

Now I am trying to write awk command which goes to column 7,replace (`|`) pipe with blank so I can treat it as single string to make my process work.

Final output should be like this:

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10
value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|"value7 text"|value8|value9|value10
```

please suggest.

Thanks,

Comment: Please add the code you have used so far.

Comment: What defines the column to "fix"? Is it always column 7? Or is it any column that matches a pipe within double quotes `"`?

Comment: @Sparhawk- We have used nawk command to fix that problem,and related to column position it can be any column position not column 7th. I just gave the example.

Comment: This is a beautiful example for an [XY - problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You say you want to do it "to make my process work", so you should ask for a solution to make your process work instead and not about how to implement a workaround that you think is suitable to make your process work.

Comment: Is it possible to solve this issue with awk,or sed command.

Comment: yes it is, but it will be an ugly workaround, please see my comment.

Comment: can we please advise how we can resolved this issue using awk command ,many thanks.

Comment: It is the vertical bar symbol. It is used to create pipes in Unix shell, but this is not its name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested with below awk command and it worked fine

```
awk -F '"' '{gsub(/\|/," ",$2);print $0}' filename
```

output

```
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10
value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6| value7 text |value8|value9|value10
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the data appears to be properly formatted CSV data, we can use a CSV parser:

```
$ csvformat -d '|' file | tr '|' ' ' | csvformat -D '|'
col1|col2|col3|col4|col5|col6|col7|col8|col9|col10
value1|value2|value3|value4|value5|value6|value7 text|value8|value9|value10
```

This uses `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to reformat the `|`-delimited data into comma-delimited data.  `tr` is then used to replace all remaining pipe symbols with spaces.  At the end, `csvformat` is again used to reformat the comma-delimited data into `|`-delimited format.

Note that `csvformat` will only add double quotes to fields if needed, or if `-U 1` is used (in which case it will double quote all fields).

Comment: its not working in my system ,but thanks for help.

Comment: @user347849 Probably because you haven't installed `csvkit`. See [installation instructions](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/1_getting_started.html#installing-csvkit)

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
sed 's/\(".*\)|\(.*"\)/\1 \2/g' file
```

> **Disclaimer:** I would not recommend doing this. Rather fix your process to make it work properly instead of introducing an ugly workaround like this. Your data is normal CSV (or "PSV") which can be read easily by any proper CSV parser.
>
> This will have issues, if you have a field e.g. like this: `value\"6|"value7|test"`.

Comment: I have tried sed command but its showing "sed: command garbled:".

Comment: maybe your `sed` doesn't know extended regex... what about the updated command?

Comment: will test the updated sed  command .